# Return object that doesn't contain any key or value of another object in Ramda

Tags: typescript, object, functional-programming, ramda.js, mediator

New to **[ramda](https://ramdajs.com/)**, building a [mediator](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/mediator) class I have an object describing registered (authorized) channels/messages. These channels are meant to be unique, both in their keys and values. At registering time, they are passed like this:

```js
enum MyMessages {
 FirstMessage = 'first:message',
 SecondMessage = 'second:message'
};

mediator.addChannels(MyMessages); // With a validator to keep them unique.
```

To remove channels I call `mediator.removeChannels(MyMessages);`.
The underlying **imperative** implementation works well:

```js
// Makes a shallow clone of the existing channels.
let result = { ...existingChannels };
// Iterates the channels to remove.
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(channelsToRemove)) {
  // Keys match.
  if (Object.keys(result).includes(key)) {
    delete result[key];
  }
  // Values match.
  if (Object.values(result).includes(value)) {
    // Finds the key for the given value.
    const k = Object.keys(result).find((a: string) => result[a] === value);
    if (k) {
      delete result[k];
    }
  }
  // Channels to remove value matches an existing key.
  if (Object.keys(result).includes(value as string)) {
    delete result[value as string];
  }
  // Channels to remove key matches an existing value.
  if (Object.values(result).includes(key)) {
    const k = Object.keys(result).find((a: string) => result[a] === key);
    if (k) {
      delete result[k];
    }
  }
}
return result;
```

It's a bit naive and could be refactored, but at the end, I get my *channels* object without the keys / values that were removed.

**I would like to replace this with `ramda` functions.**

I'm able to get overlapping keys with something like

```js
R.without(R.keys(channelsToRemove), R.keys(existingChannels))
```

But I can't understand how I can easily get the final object (e.g. without the second object's keys or values).

```js
const obj1 = {
  foo: 'bar',
  baz: 'sum'
}

const obj2 = {
  baz: 'hop'
}

const obj3 = {
  sum: 'ack'
}
```

As a result, I'd like this to happen:

- `obj1 - obj2` should return `{ foo: 'bar' }`: key overlaps key.
- `obj1 - obj3` should return `{ foo: 'bar' }`: key overlaps value.
- `obj2 - obj3` should return `{ baz: 'hop' }`: unique keys and values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Ramda version looks to me like it does what you want:

```js
const allDiff = (x, y) => fromPairs (filter (
  none (flip (includes) ([...keys (y), ... map (String) (values (y) )]))
) (toPairs (x)))

const obj1 = {foo: 'bar', baz: 'sum'}
const obj2 = {baz: 'hop'}
const obj3 = {sum: 'ack'}

console .log (allDiff (obj1, obj2))
console .log (allDiff (obj1, obj3))
console .log (allDiff (obj2, obj3))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script>const {fromPairs, filter, none, flip, includes, keys, values, map, toPairs} = R</script>
```

We use `toPairs -> filter -> fromPairs` to take apart our first object, filter the resulting key-value pairs, and then put it back together.  The filter checks that neither element (`none`) of our `key-value` pair is included in (`flip (includes)`) the list of element including the `keys` or `values` of our second object.  We add `map (String)` over the values in order to cover your `value as string`.  (I don't know TS well, but I'm guessing that this is equivalent.)

It's not clear to me, though, how much of an improvement this version is over a vanilla JS version:

```js
const allDiff = (x, y, 
  props = [...Object .keys(y), ... Object .values(y) .map (String)], 
  fn = (v) => props .includes (v)
) => Object .fromEntries (
  Object .entries (x) .filter (([k, v]) => !(fn(k) || fn (v)))
)
```

```js
const allDiff = (x, y, 
  props = [...Object .keys(y), ... Object .values(y) .map (String)], 
  fn = (v) => props .includes (v)
) => Object .fromEntries (
  Object .entries (x) .filter (([k, v]) => !(fn(k) || fn (v)))
)


const obj1 = {foo: 'bar', baz: 'sum'}
const obj2 = {baz: 'hop'}
const obj3 = {sum: 'ack'}

console .log (allDiff (obj1, obj2))
console .log (allDiff (obj1, obj3))
console .log (allDiff (obj2, obj3))
```

If you're already using Ramda, I think the Ramda one is a bit cleaner.  But I don't think it's enough of an advantage that I would add Ramda to a codebase just for that.

While I'm sure we could make this entirely point-free with enough effort, I'm guessing that doing so would make it much less readable.

Answer (score 1):

With Ramda I would use `R.pickBy`, and create a predicate (based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/75783263/5157454) that takes both the key and value of the current property using `R.unapply`:

```js
const {pipe, toPairs, flatten, map, flip, includes, none, unapply, curry, pickBy} = R

const getRemovePredicate = pipe(toPairs, flatten, map(String), flip(includes), none, unapply)

const allDiff = curry((obj, toRemove) => pickBy(
  getRemovePredicate(toRemove),
  obj
))

const obj1 = {foo: 'bar', baz: 'sum'}
const obj2 = {baz: 'hop'}
const obj3 = {sum: 'ack'}

console .log (allDiff (obj1, obj2))
console .log (allDiff (obj1, obj3))
console .log (allDiff (obj2, obj3))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you to both of you @scottsauyet and @oridrori. Both work like a charm. As a side question: In this case, does `ramda` has a positive performance impact on the function? Thanks again!

Comment: Nope. You won't see any significant difference in performance unless you map at least 20,000 items, and Ramda would probably be a bit slower due to the functions overhead. Ramda is not about performance, it's more about writing concise, functional code.

Comment: Thank you again. I'd like to understand what is happening under the hood, particularly the `map(String)` and `flip(includes)` parts. Could you explain? I guess `map(String)` is here to ensure everything (key and value) is a string, but I really don't understand the `flip(includes)`...

Comment: The `map(String)` ensures that everything is a string. The `R..includes` function accepts the predicate accepts the array as the 2nd argument. Since we want to pass the array as the 1st argument, we flip the them, so that 2nd argument is first.